# System.FormatException error when multithreading

Tags: multithreading, functional-programming, f#, locking, f#-interactive

I need to create two threads for a little F# project that implements locking to avoid a race condition. (I have scanned StackOverflow for answers to no avail hence this post)

Here is the code:

```
let bookFood _ =
    Console.WriteLine("Enter amount of grocery bags: ")
    let groceryBags = int(Console.ReadLine())
    Console.WriteLine("Enter customer name: ")
    let name = string(Console.ReadLine().ToString())
    let book bags name orders = 
        lock(bags,name) (fun()-> orders |> List.map (fun order ->
            if order.bags = bags then { order with customer = name }
            else order ))    
    orders <- book groceryBags name orders

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(WaitCallback(bookFood)) |> ignore
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(WaitCallback(bookFood)) |> ignore
Thread.Sleep(5000)
```

The problem that when I run this code the following happens:

I'm prompted to enter amount of grocery bags twice (as should be I suppose?, because I'm invoking the bookFood function twice,  right?)

Then I'm prompted to enter customer name, as soon as I enter this the application crashes with the following error: System.FormatException has been thrown, the input string is not in the correct format.

I have searched everywhere for a solution, but I'm reaching out for help now.

Clarification:

How do I solve this problem? Is it because I have coded the locking incorrectly or am I not creating two threads correctly? It works perfect when I only invoke the bookFood method once, but the task requires me to create two threads and use locking to avoid race condition , and that's when I get this error.

A big thank you to the active F# community here that is helping out, you know who you are.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the debugger, you should find that the point it breaks at is:

```
let groceryBags = int(Console.ReadLine())
```

Remember how you're "prompted to enter amount of grocery bags twice" - that's because you're running a call to `ReadLine()` on two threads.

When you enter the number of bags, the next `ReadLine` call will be the other `book` method's "number of bags", and you enter a name there, which can't be converted to an `int`, so it throws an exception saying it's not in the correct format.

If you had entered only numbers, including for the name, you shouldn't get this error.

1. `Console` functions are not thread-safe, and you really shouldn't be using it that way.
2. Use `Int32.TryParse` to see if your string does match the format instead of throwing an exception when it doesn't.
3. The lock needs a shared object between all your threads. You are creating a new tuple object in every lock - which won't do anything. Try locking on a specifically created lock object, just `let gate = new Object()` will do.

Comment: No, don't lock on `orders`. Instead create a dedicated lock object for the occasion. This and more is explained in detail here: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/lock-statement-best-practices

Comment: @BentTranberg That's better. Edited my answer.